# Cech Spectral Sequence for Cohomology with Compact Support

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, sheaf-cohomology, spectral-sequences

Using the Cech spectral sequence, we can compute the cohomology of a topological space via the cohomology of open subsets. Is there a version of this where we use cohomology with compact support? Let me describe what I'd like: If $p:X\to \text{Spec }k$ is a scheme (or a topological space), and $(U_i)_i$ a finite open covering, do we have
$$(*) \quad E_2^{p,q}=\check{\mathrm{H}}^n_c(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})\Rightarrow H^n_c(X,\mathcal{F})?$$
Since $H^n_c(X,\mathcal{F})=R^ip_{!} \mathcal{F}$, if we can show that the composition of the forgetful functor $F:\text{Sh}(X)\to \text{PSh}(X)$ with $\check{\mathrm{H}}^0_c(\mathfrak{U},-):\text{PSh}(X)\to \text{Sh}(\text{Spec }k)$, where
$$\check{\mathrm{H}}^0_c(\mathfrak{U},F)(\text{Spec }k)=\text{ker}\left(\prod_i (p\vert_{U_i})_!\mathcal{F}(k) \to \prod_{i,j} (p\vert_{U_i\cap U_j})_!\mathcal{F}(k) \right),$$
agrees with $p_!$ (i.e. $p_!=\check{\mathrm{H}}^0_c(\mathfrak{U},-)\circ F$), then $(*)$ would just be the consequence of the Grothendieck spectral sequence. Is that true, and is there a nice reference for this?

**Edit:** Maybe I ought to add that there exist one case where this is true: if $X=U\cup V$, then the spectral sequence degenerates at $E_2$ and yield Mayer-Vietoris, which is true for cohomology with compact support.

Comment: This seems false if the cover is infinite in the topological case. For example, consider an infinite $S$ with discrete topology, which is covered by singletons. Then compactly supported section of a constant $\mathbb Z$-sheaf simply means that it is zero except at finite points.

Comment: @Yai0Phah Fair enough, lets assume then that the cover is finite.

Comment: To apply the Grothendieck spectral sequence, you need to check carefully that the global section with compact support gives rise to a universal $\delta$-functor, and satisfies certain vanishing conditions. In particular, the Mayer-Vietoris sequence should be involved in the proof, instead of a corollary of the convergence of the spectral sequence.

Comment: The Mayer-Vietoris sequence for $(U,V)$ follows from the short exact sequence $0\to j_{U\cap V,!}j_{U\cap V}^*\mathcal F\to j_{U,!}j_U^*\mathcal F\oplus j_{V,!}j_V^*\mathcal F\to j_{U\cup V,!}j_{U\cup V}^*\mathcal F\to0$ which could be checked stalk-local (see Iversen's Cohomology of Sheaves). This short exact sequence is a Čech complex associated to the cover $\{U,V\}$, and you can generalize to an acyclic cosimplicial sheaf.